# Getting query string parameters from url in the UIWebView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, ios8

my question is pretty straight forward. Can someone please show me how to get the query string parameters in a url received by the UIWebView. It is pretty easy in objective c, but I need some help in swift as i'm new to the language. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the NSURL class exists the `.query` property which returns the string of everything after the ? in the url in form:
http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1&key2=value2
in this example using the code:

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1&key2=value2")
println(url.query) // Prints: Optional("key1=value1&key2=value2")
```

More information in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURL/query)

As far as getting the url from the uiwebview, you could use something along the lines of:

```
let url: NSURL = someWebView.NSURLRequest.URL
```

Comment: is there an easy way to then select the value for `key1` or `key2`?

Comment: I guess I could do `let params = url.query; let splitParams = params!.componentsSeparatedByString("=")`

Answer (score 4):

To make it a bit easier to get the value of a particular parameter you expect, you can use `URLComponents` which will parse out the query string parameters for you.

For example, if we want the value of the query string parameter `key2` in this URL:

> "https://www.example.com/path/to/resource?key1=value1&key2=value2"

We can create a URLComponents struct, then filter for the query item which matches the name, take the first one, and print its value:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.example.com/path/to/resource?key1=value1&key2=value2")
if let url = url,
    let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
    let parameterWeWant = urlComponents.queryItems?.filter({ $0.name == "key2" }).first
    print(parameterWeWant?.value ?? "")
}
```

The key (!) thing is that `urlComponents.queryItems` gives us this array of `QueryItem` structs back, which gives us an easier way to filter the parameters and get the value of the parameter we're looking for.

```
▿ Optional([key1=value1, key2=value2])
  ▿ some: 2 elements
    ▿ key1=value1
      - name: "key1"
      ▿ value: Optional("value1")
        - some: "value1"
    ▿ key2=value2
      - name: "key2"
      ▿ value: Optional("value2")
        - some: "value2"
```

Answer (score 0):

We can parse the Url params with this method,

```
func getParameterFrom(url: String, param: String) -> String? {
        guard let url = URLComponents(string: url) else { return nil }
        return url.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == param })?.value
    }

let url = "http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1&key2=value2"
let key1 = self.getParameterFrom(url: url, param: "key1")
print("\(key1)") // value1
```